# Zend Navigation, ACL and Partials

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-navigation

I have Zend Navigation object with Acl and Roles:

```
echo $this->navigation()->menu('navigation')
->setAcl($this->acl)
->setRole(($this->user ? 'user' : 'guest'))
->render();
```

and its work perfectly (hides some pages)

BUT

when i use custom partial:

```
echo $this->navigation()->menu('navigation')
->setAcl($this->acl)
->setRole(($this->user ? 'user' : 'guest'))
->setPartial('partial/twitterBootstrapNavHeadUl.phtml')
->render();
```

and this partial content

```
foreach ($this->container as $page)
    echo $this->navigation()->menu()->htmlify($page);
```

it pass to the partial $this->container **with ALL pages** (via acl setted as unaviable)

Maybe i should pass acl etc to partial

```
foreach ($this->container as $page)
    echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setAcl($this->acl)->setRole(($this->user ? 'user' : 'guest'))->htmlify($page); // ?????????????????????
```

but how to achieve it?

Is there something what I should do/know?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
foreach ($this->container as $page){
    if($this->navigation()->accept($page))
        echo $this->navigation()->menu()->htmlify($page);
}
```

Why? In a custom view you have to run the check on your own.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I spent a lot of time on documentation and I couldn't find this anywhere.

Comment: Will the answer is correct I could not get it working properly. After some digging and thinking, I used the Navigation::setDefaultAcl & Navigation::setDefaultRole to get it working. Hope it might help some one in the future

Comment: I used the setDefault methods too @Hendriq but still I had to check the acl manually as Aleksander posted.

Comment: That is true, you need to use both. Ie the check of Aleksander and the set default methods

Comment: Here is a short summary on the issue based on the #zf2 manual examples: http://blog.webdevilopers.net/?p=32